# Why does AIC formula in R appear to use one extra parameter than expected?

Tags: r, time-series, modeling, aic

I'll use an example so that you can reproduce the results

```
# mortality 
mort = ts(scan("http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/data/cmort.dat"),start=1970, frequency=52)

# temperature
temp = ts(scan("http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/data/temp.dat"), start=1970, frequency=52)

#pollutant particulates
part = ts(scan("http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa2/data/part.dat"), start=1970, frequency=52)

temp = temp-mean(temp)
temp2 = temp^2
trend = time(mort)
```

Now, fit a model for mortality data

```
fit = lm(mort ~ trend + temp + temp2 + part, na.action=NULL)
```

What I want now is to reproduce the result of the AIC command

```
AIC(fit)
[1] 3332.282
```

According to R's help file for AIC, AIC = -2 * log.likelihood + 2 * npar.
If I'm correct I think that log.likelihood is given using the following formula:

```
n = length(mort)
RSS = anova(fit)[length(anova(fit)[,2]),2] # there must be better ways to get this, anyway
(log.likelihood <- -n/2*(log(2*pi)+log(RSS/n)+1))

 [1] -1660.135
```

This is approximately equal to

```
logLik(fit)
'log Lik.' -1660.141 (df=6)
```

As far as I can tell, the number of parameters in the model are 5 (how can I get this number programmatically ??). So AIC should be given by:

```
-2 * log.likelihood + 2 * 5
[1] 3330.271
```

Ooops, it seems like I should have used 6 instead of 5 as the number of parameters. What is wrong with those calculations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
> -2*logLik(fit)+2*(length(fit$coef)+1)
[1] 3332.282
```

(you forgot; you have 6 parameter because $\sigma_{\epsilon}$ also has to be estimated!

Comment: Aww, you've beat me. +1

Comment: Thanks! Is it the same as the df=6 that LogLik returns? Could I have used -2*logLik(fit)+2*(attr(logLik(fit),"df"))  ??

Comment: @user603 Also, how did you "draw" that indexed sigma?

Comment: @gd047. LaTeX code: `$\sigma_{\epsilon}$`